# Yii CJuiAutoComplete not working

Tags: jquery, yii

I'm trying to  implement CJuiAutoComplete in my project but it is not working. I've researched the problem for the past few days and have tried everything. What appears to be happening (or not happening in this case) is that the lookup action in the controller is not being called. I also cannot get it to work if I set the source to a simple array of items. What am I doing wrong?

_form.php

```
            <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
                        'model' => $model,
                        'attribute' => 'zipcode',
                        'source' => $this->createUrl('address/lookup'),
                        'name' => 'zipcode',
                        'htmlOptions' => array('size'=>'5'),
                        'options' => array(
                            'showAnim'=>'fold',
                            'minLength' => 1,
                    )) ?>
```

AddressController.php

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('index','view'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
            'actions'=>array('create','update','lookup'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
            'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
            'users'=>array('admin'),
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}


    public function actionLookup()
    {
        echo "Lookup Action";
    }
```

Comment: did you tried  `sourceUrl` insted of `source` ? ie  `'sourceUrl'=>array('address/lookup')`

Comment: Yes, I tried sourceUrl as well. I'm stumped!

Comment: @user1417526 may be you defined a widget( a textField or something) with the same model's `zipcode` attribute in the same view file. In that case autocomplete may fail to work

Comment: I added Yii::app()->end(); after the echo call in actionLookup(). I still don't see an echo. I also don't have any conflicts with other textFields or widgets in the form. When I debug the app, it does not stop at my breakpoint in actionLookup(). It appears that the function is not being called.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, [jui's autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) expects data in the following format:

> **Expected data format**
>
> The data from local data, a url or a callback can come in two variants:
>
> An Array of Strings:
> [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]
> An Array of Objects with label and value properties:
> [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]

So in your action you've got to return Json :

```
echo CJSON::encode(array("Look up action"));
```

Edit: [CJSON docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CJSON)

Comment: I now see that my CJuiDatePicker widget is no longer working and the firebug console says that jQuery is not defined. I can only assume that both issues are related. Perhaps its a configuration issue?

Comment: did you check if jquery is being included in the generated html?

Comment: Thank you for your help is is much appreciated. The error is occurring on multiple pages. However, on this on the generated code loads jquery.js then jquery.yiiactiveform.js.

Comment: i think you either moved servers, or moved your _assets_ folder, but you have your _assets_ folder messed up. i see that you have already asked a different question regarding jquery not being included, so i suggest you wait for solutions to that question, in the meantime, you could also search for assets related problems here in S.O and in google, there will definitely be some solutions. i'm sorry that i can't be of more help, as i have never faced any assets problems yet. And returning to your original question, it was definitely not a jquery undefined problem, as i have tested with and ...

Comment: ... without returning array data back to view(to auto-complete), and without array(just string) it was not working, so i believe my answer is correct, autocomplete needs specific data format.

Comment: btw, for your assets have you actually gone to the exact folder mentioned in the generated html, and checked if the file existed? example: go to _/myapp/assets/ef86d901/jquery.yiiactiveform.js_ and confirm that _jquery.yiiactiveform.js_ actually exists, then let me know what you see

Comment: The issue is resolved. It was not a jQuery, widget, or asset issue. I had deleted the assets but the problem persisted. It appears that my installation of Yii was corrupt although everything worked except for the jui widgets. I downloaded the latest Yii framework again, extracted, and re-configured. All problems were resolved. Thank you again for your assistance!

Comment: Well, i have to ask you to try, now that the other issues are solved, using just normal `echo "Lookup Action";` and then use my method `echo CJSON::encode(array("Look up action"));`, then tell me which one works. I just tested with your normal echo, and it doesn't work. Do let me know. Otherwise all my help was in vain.

Answer (score 0):

Try this its very simple for you..

```
public function actionAutoCompleteLookup()
        {
           if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest && isset($_GET['q']))
           {

              $name = $_GET['q']; 

               $qtxt ="SELECT name FROM address WHERE name LIKE '%".$name."%'";
               $command =Yii::app()->db->createCommand($qtxt);

               $userArray =$command->queryColumn();

              $returnVal = '';
              foreach($userArray as $userAccount)
              {
                 $returnVal .= $userAccount->getAttribute('first_name').'|'
                                             .$userAccount->getAttribute('user_id')."\n";
              }
              echo $returnVal;
           }
        }
```

And in the view code like this..

```
<?php $this->widget('CAutoComplete',
          array(
                         //name of the html field that will be generated
             'name'=>'name', 
                       //replace controller/action with real ids
             'url'=>array('address/AutoCompleteLookup'), 
             'max'=>10, //specifies the max number of items to display

                         //specifies the number of chars that must be entered 
                         //before autocomplete initiates a lookup

             ));
    ?>
```

its work fine...

Comment: Since CAutoComplete is now deprecated I'd prefer to stay with something that will be supported long-term. That is why I chose the jui widget.

Answer (score 0):

It Jquery Problem please diable or remove jquery-min.js  file then check its works fine.